# Template for custom type in mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I've been learning Mezzanine and currently experimenting with themes. So far, this is what I have:

```
-projectA <- mezzanine app
-theemeA/ <- custom theme
  -admin.py
  -models.py
  -__init__.py
 -templates/
   -pages/
      -about-us.html
      -aboutus.html
   -index.html
   -base.html
   -about-us.html
```

TheemeA is included in the project and I can see the customized index and base.html. Now I want to create a series of pages that have a common look that will go in the About US section on the site. I want this new content type to extend the base.html.

I created models.py in TheemeA; pulled from [here](https://rodmtech.net/docs/mezzanine/a-mezzanine-tutorial-take-2/#part-4-creating-new-page-types) and slightly altered for testing. I know I will need to rework some of this.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page, RichText

class AboutUs(Page, RichText):
    """
    About Us Base Content Type
    """
    add_toc = models.BooleanField(_("aboutus"), default=False,
                                  help_text=_("Include a list of child links"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("About Us")
        verbose_name_plural = _("About Us")
```

I've also included this new model in the admin.py for TheemeA and it shows up as a content type in the UI with a text edit field. Now I want to create a custom template that extends the model so I can customize the appearance. However, I am not able to get mezzanine to pull up my template. I've been looking at [this](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-templates) and it's not helping.

I've tried multiple variations of about-us.html and aboutus.html in that folder and in folder called pages, but can't get it to work. Can someone please provide a bit of guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model looks fine
admin.py should be similar to:

```
from .models import AboutUs,
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin
admin.site.register(AboutUs, PageAdmin)
```

Create a page instance in the admin UI. 
Usually a space in the title becomes - eg 'About Us' becomes 'about-us.html.
And it needs to be within the pages directory.

Comment: Thanks, admin.py has that and another import: from django.contrib import admin. What I am looking to do is to create a new content type 'About Us' and have a series of pages that look the same, but content can be managed through mezzanine. I want them all to have the same template; I don't wan to create an html file for each page based on it's title. It defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: You won't need to create new html, every time you add a 'About us' page from the drop down in admin (alongside RichText, Link, Gallery) it will use the about-us.html template no matter what the title of the page is.

Comment: I have an about-us.html file in themea/templates/pages/ and I can't get it to show up when I browse to the page in mezzanine.

Comment: I updated the filestructure in the post. Can you Check it out? Also, when I have these files in there and browse to the page, it shows up without any content. Not even the text I enter in WYSIWIG when creating it.

Comment: is about-us.html a blank file? if you add something and go to the url does it appear? if it does, copy the contents of richtextpage.html into about-us.html

Comment: If I add some HTML in there, I don't see it in the markup. If I clear it out and just add some random text, I still don't see it and instead see just an empty block from base.html (where the content should be). In other words (I think) it still pulls from page.html.

Comment: Strange. What's the file structure of projectA? is there a templates directory in there?

Comment: projectA has settings, local_settings, urls and wsgi, regular stuff. Thanks for your help by the way. I know I am doing something wrong; but I can't pin point what. I even checked out the code at views.page and I can't figure out why my template is not coming up. Even weirder, why is there no content from that content type at all if there is a template in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90981/discussion-between-joeskru-and-browskie).